# starting container process caused "exec: \"./boot.sh\": permission denied": unknown

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There is a **back.Dockerfile**.

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /src

COPY . ./

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN chmod +x boot.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

There is a **boot.sh** in which I do migrations for Django and then start the service.

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    python /src/manage.py migrate
    if [[ "$?" == "0" ]]; then
        break
    fi
    echo Upgrade command failed, retrying in 5 secs...
    sleep 5
done

exec python /src/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

There is a **docker-compose**.

```
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: deploy/back.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    ports:
      - 8888:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.24
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASS}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_NAME}
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/vennepriser-db:/var/lib/mysql
```

When I run `sudo docker-compose up`, I get the error

Tried also such options

- `ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]`
- `ENTRYPOINT ["/src/boot.sh"]`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `volumes:` block of the `docker-compose.yml` file inside the `backend` container.

When you have a `volumes:` block that injects host-system code into a container like this, it completely replaces whatever content was in the corresponding path in the image.  If you make changes to the image filesystem in the Dockerfile (like `RUN chmod`) but then mount something over it, those changes will be hidden.

A typical motivation for this sort of setup is to do active development on the code in a container setup.  You can use a hybrid Docker/host setup for this: use Compose to start dependencies like the database, but use an ordinary host development environment (*e.g.*, a Python virtual environment) to build the code.  You'll need to make sure you have a reasonable configuration system to adjust things like the database location, which will be different in the different environments (`localhost:3307` in host-based development, `db:3306` in the pure-container environment).

Comment: Thnx. I get error `Cannot start service backend: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"boot.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

Comment: In the Dockerfile as you've quoted it in the question, it tries to run `boot.sh` which looks for it on `$PATH`.  The error in the question title would try to run `./boot.sh`.